# Android Adapter with Irregular format/views for GridView

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-listview, android-gridview

I'm making a custom Adapter, FieldAdapter, that extends BaseAdapter. I am created a GridView of LinearLayout views which contain a TextView and either a Spinner OR an EditText.

It seems that, after looking around a lot, that the optimized method is to use the ViewHolder method. But this seems to be optimized for a list of items that all share the same attributes.

What makes this a potential problem is the fact that I may have 4 views with a TextView and EditText, and another 5 that contain a TextView and a spinner so I can't assume a certain layout.

Is it optimal to have logic in my getView method that checks what kind of view needs to be returned for each item or is there a better way? Should I just have ViewHolder objects to hold the corresponding layouts? ie DropdownViewHolder and TextViewHolder?

Does this render the convertView useless?

The following is my code that works, but I've noticed that if I have a large list of items and scroll up and down quickly my entire list disappears which leads me to believe I'm not doing something correctly.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout layoutSection = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dropdown, null);

        TextView labelText = new TextView(this.context);
        labelText.setText(data.get(position).getLabelText());
        labelText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layoutSection.addView(labelText);

        if (data.get(position).getFieldType().equalsIgnoreCase("dropdown")) {
            Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this.context);
            spinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            // Options
            final List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, options);
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);


            layoutSection.addView(spinner);
        } else if (data.get(position).getFieldType().equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
            EditText textbox = new EditText(this.context);
            textbox.setText("Hi");
            textbox.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            layoutSection.addView(textbox);
        }

        return layoutSection;
    } else {
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see those methods: getItemViewType & getViewTypeCount